# My discord bot keeps spamming the DMs, anyway to fix this?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to do a broadcast feature, but when I try to use it just spams(only my inbox for some reason), anyway to prevent this from happening? (I am new at JavaScript)

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "dmall",
  description: "Broadcast",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    message.delete();
    if (message.author.id === "294835623028588546") {
      message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
        var DM = args;
        message.member.send(DM);
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `message.member` so it mentions you. You should use `member`, rather than `message.member`. In code that is below I fixed it.

````
  name: "dmall",
  description: "Broadcast",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    message.delete();
    if (message.author.id === "294835623028588546") {
      message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
        var DM = args;
        member.send(DM);
      });
    }
  },
};```
````